# Changing the last datarow from a asp:repeater table if data is shown in asp:label using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to change the last value of a asp:repeater > table > tr > asp:label. If a condition is true. To be more expecific, i have the values of the bbdd stored in lblJournee and lblDateFormation. I have another lblDateFormation2 to take the value of the last date. I want to change the value of the last row in my repeater if this condition is made. I hope is understood my problem, i am quite new and trying to learn.

CODE FOR .aspx:

```
<asp:repeater id="rep_Dates" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table id="tblRepDates">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th rowspan="1" colspan="2">Dates</th>
                                        </tr>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="sombre">                                             
                                                <asp:label runat="server" id="lbl_DateFormation" text='<%# Eval("[DateFormation]")%>'></asp:label>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="sombre">
                                                <asp:label runat="server" id="lbl_DemiJournee" text='<%# Eval("[DemiJournee]")%>'></asp:label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </table>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:repeater>
```

CODE FOR .aspx.vb:

```
Private Sub BindRepeaterData(ByVal noformationL As String)

        Dim conSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim cmdSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

        conSQL.ConnectionString = Application("BACKstr")
        conSQL.Open()

        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "select convert(char,[DateFormation],103) AS DateFormation,[DemiJournee] from [EXT$FORM_FormationDates] where NoFormation='" & Replace(noformationL, "'", "''") & "' and TypeDates = 0 order by DateFormation,DemiJourneeInt"

        Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
        Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)

        da.Fill(ds)

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim lblDateFormation As New Label
            Dim lblJournee As New Label
            Dim lblDateFormation2 As String = ""
            Dim index As Integer = 0

            rep_Dates.Visible = True
            rep_Dates.DataSource = ds
            rep_Dates.DataBind()
            'je mets (1) parce que c'est le deuxieme element du repeater
            lblDateFormation = rep_Dates.Controls(1).FindControl("lbl_DateFormation")
            lblJournee = rep_Dates.Controls(1).FindControl("lbl_DemiJournee")

            For Each item As RepeaterItem In rep_Dates.Items

                lblDateFormation = item.FindControl("lbl_DateFormation")
                lblJournee = item.FindControl("lbl_DemiJournee")
                'si les dates sont les memes on met une seule ligne avec lblJournee = "Journee"
                'il faut mettre que la premiere date quelque soit la lblJournee reste M
                'item.ItemIndex = 0 
                'Pour tous les elements on peut se retrouver avec:
                '   - Le premier element est Matin ou AM est la date sera prise
                '   - Si le deuxieme element est AM et la date est egale a la premiere...on efface la ligne et le premier element prend la valeur JOURNEE
                '   - Si le deuxieme element est AM et la date est different...On ecrit AM
                '   - Si le deuxieme element est Matin on ecrit Matin
                If item.ItemIndex = 0 Then

                    If lblJournee.Text = "Matin" Then

                        lblJournee.Text = "Matin"
                        lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text
                        index = item.ItemIndex

                    Else

                        lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi"
                        lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text
                        index = item.ItemIndex

                    End If

                Else

                    If lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi" And lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text Then

                        item.Visible = False

                        'Por cada fila que contenga Matin la cambiamos por journee 
                        'Eliminamos la ultima linea y el valor journee sera el de esta o eliminamos esta linea y cambiamos matin por journée
                        lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text
                        index = item.ItemIndex

                    ElseIf lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi" And lblDateFormation2 <> lblDateFormation.Text Then

                        lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi"
                        lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text
                        index = item.ItemIndex

                    ElseIf lblJournee.Text = "Matin" Then

                        lblJournee.Text = "Matin"
                        lblDateFormation2 = lblDateFormation.Text
                        index = item.ItemIndex

                    End If

                End If

            Next

        Else
            rep_Dates.Visible = False
        End If

        conSQL.Close()

    End Sub
```

I hope is all clear. Thanks in advance to any help

**Additional code** for ItemDataBound event (taken from comment below for clarity)

```
Sub R1_ItemDataBound(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rep_Dates.ItemDataBound()
Dim lblJournee As New Label 
Dim lblDateFormation As New Label 
   If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then 
      If e.Item.ItemIndex = Session("dataRowCount") And lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi" Then 
         lblJournee.Text = "Journée" 
      End If 
   End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Rafael.. It seems that I got confused with your requirement. I thought you only wanted to change the data in **last** row. I now can see that you wish to compare two rows at a time until you have compared all rows. The way to achieve this is to have 2 datasets. The 1st is populated with data from SQL. The second is populated as we compare each pair of rows. All this is done as you thought in your BindRepeaterData Sub. Forget all I said about the ItemDataBound event.

Here is my solution which I have checked with the data you supplied.

```
Private Sub BindRepeaterData()
    'For test I removed param

    Dim conSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmdSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    conSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConn").ToString
    'Change your connection string...
    conSQL.Open()

    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    cmdSQL.CommandText = "select convert(char,[DateFormation],103) AS DateFormation,[DemiJournee] from [TblTest] order by DateFormation"
    'Change your Sql

    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
    Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)

    da.Fill(ds)

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        'Create a new dataset with table where we will store final data
        Dim dsfinal As New DataSet()
        dsfinal.Tables.Add("FinalData")
        dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DateFormation")
        dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DemiJournee")

        'Now we will go through ds comparing rows and adding as appropriate to dsfinal then bind dsfinal to repeater.

        Dim totalrows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Dim rowpointer As Integer = 0
        Dim r = 0
        If totalrows > 2 Then
            'We have more than two rows
            'We compare one row against the next row until we get to the last two rows.
            Do While r < totalrows - 2
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(r + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                    'Both compared rows have same date
                    'We add just one row to table
                    dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
                    r += 2 'add 2 to r
                    rowpointer = r 'add 2 to rowpointer
                Else
                    'The two rows have different dates
                    'add first comparitor as a row.
                    'we leave the next row to make comparision with the row after it
                    dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    r += 1
                    rowpointer = r
                End If
            Loop

        End If

        If rowpointer < totalrows - 1 Then
            'We need to compare the remaining two rows
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                'Both compared rows have same date
                'We add just one row to table
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
            Else
                'The two rows have different dates
                'add both rows
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
            End If
        Else
            'We only have one record
            dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
        End If

        'dsfinal now contains the correct data.
        'clear original ds
        ds = Nothing

        rep_Dates.Visible = True
        rep_Dates.DataSource = dsfinal
        rep_Dates.DataBind()

        dsfinal = Nothing
    Else
        rep_Dates.Visible = False
    End If

    conSQL.Close()

End Sub
```

Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Thanks Mych i am going to try and tomorrow i will let you know, thanks again

Comment: Mych, if i want to put the rows that have Journee and theirs dates are correlative together in one row like this:             15/10/2014 to 17/10/2014 Journée                                    20/10/2014 Matin...                                                 Do you think is possible? My problem is that the date comes out as string from the database....I am trying like you did? with two datasets and comparing but at the moment i have no luck...How can i compare the strings, bit difficult no?

Comment: I think you would have to use 3 tables. The 1st will be populated by Sql. The second will be as above which will compare the dates and change to Journée if the dates are the same. The final one will compare the DemiJournee field. Have a go this should be a bit more simple than the previous comparison. Post your code... probably as a new Question if you run into problems. Note I made some edits to my last answer as I had some surplus code that is not used.

Comment: I just posted another question of this subject, if you want and got the time i will appreciate any help, thanks Mych

Answer (score 0):

I would bind as normal and then have an ItemDataBound event which will fire as each item is bound. You could then check if the item is the last item and make your change to that items label.

Comment: Thanks Mych i am going to try i will let you know if it worked

Comment: I have been looking how to use the itemdatabound event but i am not sure of what i have to put Inside. Do you think it could be done for my problem? I think i should put Inside some part of the code above...

Comment: It should do... I would add a session("dataRowCount") = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count just after you fill your da in your code above. Then in itemdatabound event check to see in rowbound is the last row by comparing to session("dataRowCount"). If true then find the lable you want in that row and change as required.

Comment: Dim lblJournee As New Label

        If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then
            If Session("dataRowCount") = rep_Dates.Items(1).ItemIndex Then
                lblJournee.Text = "Journée"

            End If
        End If

Comment: index out of range...I dont know how to do, any help? I don't know how to compare with the row that i want

Comment: Sub R1_ItemDataBound(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        Dim lblJournee As New Label
        Dim lblDateFormation As New Label
        If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Then
            If e.Item.ItemIndex = Session("dataRowCount") And lblJournee.Text = "Après-midi" Then

                lblJournee.Text = "Journée"

            End If
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Ok first bit... Index out of range this usually means that you are referring to an index which does not exist. Note that in VB, index values start from 0.. so your first repeater will be 0 and your last will be dataRowCount-1. The same goes for items in a row. The first item will be index 0.

Comment: Next you seem to be creating a new label instead of referring to the actual label in the repeater row.

Comment: Hi put this new code to find the answer:Sub R1_ItemDataBound(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        If e.Item.ItemIndex = Session("dataRowCount") And e.Item.FindControl("lbl_DemiJournee").ToString = "Après-midi" Then

            e.Item.DataItem = "Journée"

        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Hi Mych, i though this was it but still don't know, any advice:

Comment: Sub R1_ItemDataBound(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
            (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
            'Si coinciden el indice y el apresmidi entonces sera
            If CType(e.Item.FindControl("lbl_DemiJournee"), Label).Text = "Matin" And Session("dataRowCount") = -1 Then

                CType(e.Item.FindControl("lbl_DemiJournee"), Label).Text = "Journée"

            End If

        End If



    End Sub

Comment: OK Rafael... I will create a test app with your code... I will need to do this a little later as I'm in work at moment. Will post update later today if that is OK.

Comment: Could you post a quick table with typical values for your sql result... 5 rows should be enough.

Comment: Dates

15/01/2014  Matin  
15/01/2014  Après-midi  
16/01/2014  Matin  
16/01/2014  Après-midi  
17/01/2014  Matin  
20/01/2014  Après-midi  
27/01/2014  Après-midi  
28/01/2014  Matin  
29/01/2014  Matin 
What i want is: when the dates are the same for Matin et Après-midi, that we can put Journée and put only one date.