# Display data of continuous date in gridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a table1 as under

```
 
____________________________________________________
|Name |   From   |   To     | City |  Designation   | 
____________________________________________________
|  A  | 01/01/02 | 01/01/03 |Delhi |      ADM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  A  | 02/01/03 | 01/01/04 |Mumbai|      ADM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  A  | 02/01/04 | 01/01/05 |Delhi |       DM       |
_____________________________________________________
|  A  | 02/01/05 | 01/01/06 |Delhi |       DM       |
_____________________________________________________   
|  A  | 02/01/06 | 01/01/07 |Mumbai|       DM      |
_____________________________________________________
```

I want to view data-" When did "A" stay in Delhi for Last time" and the display should be as under:

**Name---From-----To-------City-----Designation**

A-----02/01/04---01/01/05--Delhi----DM

A-----02/01/05---01/01/06--Delhi----DM

I want to display data in gridview
I am working with vb.net

please help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add filtering to your datasource and rebind your grid.

Added to answer for clarity
You are not explaining very clearly.... If you have data as described above...

```
Select Top(2) [Name], [From], [To], [City], [Designation] 
From [TableName] Where [City] = @City And [Name] = @Name Order By [From] Desc
```

will give you the last two times that @Name went to @City which is what you have asked for.

I would also suggest changing files From and To to DateFrom and DateTo so as there is less confusion with SQL FROM and TO keywords

Comment: Thanks. If I filter, it displays entire data when A was staying in Delhi i.e. line no. 1, 3 & 4 but I want to display data "when did A stay in Delhi last time continuously" i.e. line no. 3 & 4. Please help.

Comment: Filter so that it selects the Top(2) with the date desc.

Comment: Thanks, only in this case I can select top 2 with desc but it will not work where top 3 or 4 or more uncertain data in database. sir I think this will not work. Sir, is there any way to select continuous date?

Comment: See my additional comment in answer pane

Comment: Sir I am sorry for not making my question clear. I wanted to know when "A" was posted in Delhi continuously that may be in 3,4 or more times in different post. Therefore, selection of top will not work sir.

Comment: Your Question did state "When did "A" stay in Delhi for Last time". What you need to do here is to select all records for A in City and Date order. Then compare row by row to see if A is in the same City and the date is a continuation from previous row.

Comment: One solution would be to pull data into datatable an iterate through each row comparing dates. If the dates are sequential then group them together... have a look at my answer to this question It should give you a good idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705111/changing-the-last-datarow-from-a-asprepeater-table-if-data-is-shown-in-asplabe

Comment: sir would you be kind enough to send me codes for this case.

Comment: The code is all there... see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547647/changing-the-last-datarow-from-a-asprepeater-table-if-data-is-shown-in-asplabe for the users original question which has the repeater markup.