# Changing the last datarow from a asp:repeater table if data is shown in asp:label using vb.net using strings of dates

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have my dates changed to Journee if the 2 rows have the same date, but now i need to put together the dates that follow each other and have Journee. How can i do this, tried this code but it is not working, thanks in advance

Private Sub BindRepeaterData(ByVal noformationL As String)

```
    Dim conSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmdSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    conSQL.ConnectionString = Application("BACKstr")
    conSQL.Open()

    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    cmdSQL.CommandText = "select convert(char,[DateFormation],103) AS DateFormation,[DemiJournee] from [EXT$FORM_FormationDates] where NoFormation='" & Replace(noformationL, "'", "''") & "' and TypeDates = 0 order by DateFormation,DemiJourneeInt"

    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
    Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)

    da.Fill(ds)

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        'On fait un premier nouveau dataset avec table pour y mettre les données finales de DemiJournee            
        Dim dsfinal As New System.Data.DataSet()
        dsfinal.Tables.Add("FinalData")
        dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DateFormation")
        dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DemiJournee")
        'On suit le DS en comparant les rows et additionant a dsfinal et puis binding dsfinal to repeater
        Dim totalrows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Dim rowpointer As Integer = 0
        Dim r = 0
        If totalrows > 2 Then
            'Si nous avons plus de 2 rows
            'On compare 1 row avec la suivante row jusqu'arrivé a les deux derniere rows                
            Do While r < totalrows - 2
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(r + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                    'Les deux rows a comparé on la meme date
                    'Nous mettons seulemenent un row au lieu de deux dans la table
                    dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")                        
                    r += 2 '+1 to r
                    rowpointer = r '+1 to rowpointer
                Else
                    'Les 2 rows on differentes dates
                    'On met en premier le comparateur comme row.
                    'On laisse la suivante row pour la comparer avec la row apres elle.
                    dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    r += 1
                    rowpointer = r
                End If
            Loop

        End If

        If rowpointer < totalrows - 1 Then
            'On a besoin de comparer les deux restantes rows
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                'Les deux rows comparées on la meme date
                'Nous mettons seulement 1 row dans la table
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
            Else
                'Les 2 rows on dates différentes
                'On mets les 2 rows dans la table
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
                dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
            End If
        Else
            'Nous avons seulement un historique(record)
            dsfinal.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
        End If

        ds = Nothing

        If dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'On fait un premier nouveau dataset avec table pour y mettre les données finales de DemiJournee            
            Dim dsfinal2 As New System.Data.DataSet()
            dsfinal2.Tables.Add("FinalData")
            dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DateFormation")
            dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Columns.Add("DemiJournee")
            'On suit le DS en comparant les rows et additionant a dsfinal et puis binding dsfinal to repeater
            Dim totalrows2 = dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            Dim rowpointer2 As Integer = 0
            Dim r2 = 0
            If totalrows2 > 2 Then
                'Si nous avons plus de 2 rows
                'On compare 1 row avec la suivante row jusqu'arrivé a les deux derniere rows                
                Do While r2 < totalrows2 - 2
                    If dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" Then
                        'Les deux rows a comparé on la meme date
                        'Nous mettons seulemenent un row au lieu de deux dans la table
                        dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DateFormation") + " au " + dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
                        r2 += 1 '+1 to r
                        rowpointer2 = r2 '+1 to rowpointer
                    Else
                        'Les 2 rows on differentes dates
                        'On met en premier le comparateur comme row.
                        'On laisse la suivante row pour la comparer avec la row apres elle.
                        dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DemiJournee"))
                        dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
                        r2 += 2
                        rowpointer2 = r2
                    End If
                Loop

            End If

            If rowpointer2 < totalrows2 - 1 Then
                'On a besoin de comparer les deux restantes rows
                If dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" Then
                    'Les deux rows comparées on la meme date
                    'Nous mettons seulement 1 row dans la table
                    dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
                Else
                    'Les 2 rows on dates différentes
                    'On mets les 2 rows dans la table
                    dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2 + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2 + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
                End If
            Else
                'Nous avons seulement un historique(record)
                dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer2).Item("DemiJournee"))
            End If

            'clear le ds original
            dsfinal = Nothing

            rep_Dates.Visible = True
            rep_Dates.DataSource = dsfinal2
            rep_Dates.DataBind()

            dsfinal2 = Nothing

        Else
            rep_Dates.Visible = False
        End If

    Else
        rep_Dates.Visible = False
    End If

    conSQL.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I just found the solution, i think, i changed the code to

Comment: Do While r2 < totalrows2 - 2
If dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DemiJournee")="Journée" Then
dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DateFormation") +"au"+ dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
r2 += 2 rowpointer2 = r2 
Else
dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2).Item("DemiJournee"))
dsfinal2.Tables("FinalData").Rows.Add(dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsfinal.Tables(0).Rows(r2 + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
r2 += 2
rowpointer2 = r2
End If
Loop

Comment: Looks good... Do your testing... check that the code works if only one record is returned check that the last record is also considered and not left out. These are the issues I came across when helping with initial sort. Otherwise well done!

Comment: I have this working for my data

15/01/2014 au 16/01/2014  Journée  
17/01/2014  Matin  
20/01/2014  Après-midi  
27/01/2014  Après-midi  
28/01/2014  Matin  
29/01/2014  Matin 

But when i put the third value Journée i have got this:

15/01/2014 au 16/01/2014  Journée  
17/01/2014 au 20/01/2014  Journée  
27/01/2014  Après-midi  
28/01/2014  Matin  
29/01/2014  Matin  
Instead of:                                               15/01/2014 au 17/01/2014  Journée   
27/01/2014  Après-midi  
28/01/2014  Matin  
29/01/2014  Matin                                                what can i do?

Comment: I think i have to compare the string but how to compare that is a date when is a string? is possible? i have to convert the string into a dateFormatString or something like that? I can do a loop until the dates are not following and the DemiJournee <> "Journée"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Rafael... my solution...
I have created two repeaters so that I can see the first transformation and the second. You can just bind the last transformation to the repeater you have...

Any Questions... please ask.

```
Private Sub BindRepeaterData()
    'For test I removed param

    Dim conSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmdSQL As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

    conSQL.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConn").ToString
    'Change your connection string...
    conSQL.Open()

    cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
    cmdSQL.CommandText = "select convert(char,[DateFormation],103) AS DateFormation,[DemiJournee] from [TblTest] order by DateFormation"
    'Change your Sql

    Dim ds As New System.Data.DataSet()
    Dim da As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)

    da.Fill(ds)

    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        'Create a new dataset with table where we will store new data
        Dim dsTemp As New DataSet()
        dsTemp.Tables.Add("TempData")
        dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Columns.Add("DateFormation")
        dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Columns.Add("DemiJournee")

        'Now we will go through ds comparing two rows at a time.
        'If the two rows have the same date the only add one row to TempData changing the DemiJournee field to Journée.
        'Else if not the same date then add one row but leave the second as we need to next compare it with its successor.

        Dim totalrows = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        Dim rowpointer As Integer = 0
        Dim r = 0
        If totalrows > 2 Then
            'We have more than two rows
            'We compare one row against the next row until we get to the last two rows.
            Do While r < totalrows - 2
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(r + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                    'Both compared rows have same date
                    'We add just one row to table and change DemiJournee field to Journée
                    dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
                    r += 2 'add 2 to r (we do not need to compare the second row as we have just condenced it)
                    rowpointer = r 'add 2 to rowpointer
                Else
                    'The two rows have different dates
                    'add first comparitor as a row.
                    'we leave the second row to make comparision with the row after it
                    dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    r += 1
                    rowpointer = r
                End If
            Loop

        End If

        If rowpointer < totalrows - 1 Then
            'We need to compare the remaining two rows
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation") = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation") Then
                'Both compared rows have same date
                'We add just one row to table
                dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
            Else
                'The two rows have different dates
                'add both rows
                dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
                dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
            End If
        Else
            'We only have one record
            dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
        End If

        'dsTemp now contains the corrected data.

        rep_Dates.Visible = True
        rep_Dates.DataSource = dsTemp
        rep_Dates.DataBind()

        'clear original ds so that we can sort our data again
        ds.Tables(0).Clear()


        'The second sort needs to go through TempData comparing two rows but this time compare the DemiJournee field
        'If the two rows have Journée as their DemiJournee value AND the dates are sequential then store then as
        '10/01/2014 - 11/01/2014 Journée... continue comparing with the next row. If that is Journée and a sequential date
        'then we would need to store as 10/01/2014 - 12/01/2014 Journée and so on.
        'If not sequential or not Journée then store as original.

        Dim sd As String = "" 'used to store the start date of our sequence
        Dim cd As String = "" 'used to store the compare date of our sequence
        Dim ed As String = "" 'used to store the end date or our sequence

        totalrows = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows.Count
        rowpointer = 0
        r = 0

        If totalrows > 2 Then
            'We have more than two rows
            'We compare one row against the next row until we get to the last two rows.
            Do While r < totalrows - 2
                If dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" And dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r + 1).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" Then
                    'Both compared rows have DemiJournee = "Journée"
                    If sd = "" Then
                        'We have no startdate so start a new sequence
                        sd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DateFormation")
                        cd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DateFormation")
                        ed = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r + 1).Item("DateFormation")

                        If CDate(ed) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, CDate(cd)) Then
                            'The two date are sequential...
                            'We don't add any rows until we run out of compared rows or sequential dates
                            r += 1
                            rowpointer = r
                        Else
                            'The two dates are not sequential. We add the first row and leave the second to compare with the next row in line
                            ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee"))
                            r += 1
                            rowpointer = r
                            sd = ""
                            cd = ""
                            ed = ""
                        End If
                    Else
                        'we already have a start date
                        cd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee")
                        ed = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r + 1).Item("DemiJournee")
                        If CDate(ed) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, CDate(cd)) Then
                            'The two date are sequential...
                            'We don't add any rows until we run out of compared rows or sequential dates
                            r += 1
                            rowpointer = r
                        Else
                            'The two dates are not sequential.
                            'Our sequence has broken so we finish this sequence by adding a new row 
                            'sd - ed Journée
                            ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(sd.ToString & " - " & ed.ToString, "Journée")
                            r += 1
                            rowpointer = r
                            sd = ""
                            cd = ""
                            ed = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    'The two rows have different DemiJournee
                    If sd = "" Then
                        'We have no squence so
                        'add first comparitor as a row.
                        'we leave the second row to make comparision with the row after it
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee"))
                        r += 1
                        rowpointer = r
                    Else
                        'we have a sequence and our sequence has broken so we finish this sequence by adding a new row
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(sd.ToString & " - " & ed.ToString, "Journée")
                        r += 1
                        rowpointer = r
                        sd = ""
                        cd = ""
                        ed = ""
                    End If

                End If
            Loop
        End If

        'Now finish off with remaining rows
        If rowpointer < totalrows - 1 Then
            'We need to compare the remaining two rows
            If dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" And dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee") = "Journée" Then
                'Both compared rows have DemiJournee = "Journée"
                If sd = "" Then
                    'We have no startdate so start a new sequence
                    sd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation")
                    cd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation")
                    ed = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation")

                    If CDate(ed) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, CDate(cd)) Then
                        'The two date are sequential...
                        'These are the last two rows so we ad one condenced row
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(sd.ToString & " - " & ed.ToString, "Journée")
                    Else
                        'The two dates are not sequential. We add two new rows
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    End If
                Else
                    'we already have a start date
                    cd = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r).Item("DemiJournee")
                    ed = dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(r + 1).Item("DemiJournee")
                    If CDate(ed) = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, CDate(cd)) Then
                        'The two date are sequential...
                        'These are the last two rows so we ad one condenced row
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(sd.ToString & " - " & ed.ToString, "Journée")
                    Else
                        'The two dates are not sequential.
                        'Our sequence has broken so we finish this sequence by adding a new row 
                        'sd - ed Journée
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(sd.ToString & " - " & cd.ToString, "Journée")
                        'plus the last row
                        ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
                    End If
                End If
                ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), "Journée")
            Else
                'The two rows have different dates
                'add both rows
                ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
                ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer + 1).Item("DemiJournee"))
            End If
        Else
            'We only have one record
            ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DateFormation"), dsTemp.Tables("TempData").Rows(rowpointer).Item("DemiJournee"))
        End If



        rep_DemiJournee.Visible = True
        rep_DemiJournee.DataSource = ds
        rep_DemiJournee.DataBind()

        dsTemp = Nothing
        ds = Nothing
    Else
        rep_Dates.Visible = False
        rep_DemiJournee.Visible = False
    End If

    conSQL.Close()

End Sub
```

Result with data you supplied gives...

> **rep_Dates**
>
> Dates
> 15/01/2014  Journée
> 16/01/2014  Journée
> 17/01/2014  Matin
> 20/01/2014  Après-midi
> 27/01/2014  Après-midi
> 28/01/2014  Matin
> 29/01/2014  Matin
>
> **rep_DemiJouree**
>
> Dates
> 15/01/2014 - 16/01/2014  Journée
> 17/01/2014  Matin
> 20/01/2014  Après-midi
> 27/01/2014  Après-midi
> 28/01/2014  Matin
> 29/01/2014  Matin

Comment: Your answer is fantastic Mych, thanks again, it solved my problem perfectly and i understood everybit of it. When more problems will come i will let you know if you are available to help me learn. Congratulations again.